# Looking for a software that enables bluetooth packet captures in windows

Tags: windows, bluetooth, packet-capture

I am looking for something similar to wireshark, but for windows (wireshark exists on windows but does not support bluetooth). It should be able to capture packets going to/from an attached bluetooth device.

Bonus features would include the ability to send packets that it has previously capture (i.e. pretend to be the device)

Free and Open Source is preferred, but if none exist I would also appreciate paid options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open source project called [Project Ubertooth](http://www.wallofsheep.com/pages/ubertooth-guide) which can monitor and capture *some* bluetooth packets - it is a combined hardware/software solution.  There is also a pure python [library](https://github.com/hackgnar/pyubertooth) to interact with the same hardware.

You can also keep an eye on [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) as the web site indicates that some work on Bluetooth is on the horizon - using the btbb library [libbtbb](https://github.com/greatscottgadgets/libbtbb) ***which wireshark can also use.***